# Powershell write object to Excel

Tags: powershell, csv, xlsx

I have results that I extracted from a CSV file and I want to write them to an xlsx file.
This is how I export the results:

```
gc "C:\File.csv" | Group -NoElement |? Count -gt 1
```

This is the rsulte:

```
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
    4 a                        
    3 b                        
    3 c                        
    2 d
```

and i want to write to xlsx like this:

[image]

If there is already data in the file then just write in a new line without deleting the old one

Comment: It might be helpful if you were clearer about whether you're writing to a csv or whether you're writing to an xlsx.  Writing to a csv, export-csv is your friend.  Writing to xlsx is going to require different techniques.

Comment: Read from csv & Write to xlsx

Comment: This becomes much easier if you download one of the commonly used excel modules. Otherwise you'll have to use COM objects.